# I want to convert JSON file into data.table in r

Tags: json, r, data.table

I have been facing a problem to convert json file into data.table in r,
I have using the `fromJSON` function from the `RJSONIO` package but I am not getting the desired output.

[Here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=18.9249788%20,72.8247779&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=busdepo&key=AIzaSyABV2WX4oFmVAgP61vDzjLCxhFEiN0d5aA) is the link from which I got the JSON object using `getURL`.

JSON object is given below.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CoQC_AAAAD5d9OlUyry65wwf069o_yY_yuPswsNO0_09Q3dne0_Zyu3ubeRm6pY0IAz7TScgjuHQBc0XW-LPz5dIXK9dAvYf_6yrcUW0ifZ33QzO3YNl7lFcKxQTZje9eJp9E_ahoE5JPVEfnhiqZYV74WQikxJoD44FM7DlFqHDE5G8lTiTsfIhRIJo769JjGSjyhtC3UtTSzz9CVLzaiyk2PEBlq1ARk5xdnW0dEaKEed5FaGg1EkGDickRFf1jxM0DuKicfgy03iaobdJ77Wce6PhsH4OrEOnhPpF5MjgAXOTyAKFg5Su63BhB3vsqjzu_c-JBmz9P2YltIU9yqayl0_LkjkSEMBmNgKELkPWAa1ykqBkAE8aFJ7yB_bLCvDJg8XUpE80oEt_ZB7l",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 18.93224529999999,
               "lng" : 72.82643779999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 18.9446469,
                  "lng" : 72.830484
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 18.926386,
                  "lng" : 72.821804
               }
            }
         },
```

I want to find out near by from google map for one of the  perticular address.

So, please help me to complete this task i.e to convert json file into data.table

Comment: your json file is incomplete. What is the expected output?

Comment: thanks for quick reply...

Comment: my expected output should be data comes into various variable,like all lat are come into lat column and lng comes into lng column

Comment: try `jsonlite` package

Answer (score 0):

As @jangorecki mentioned, you can use the `fromJSON()` function from the `jsonlite`package to turn a JSON object into a dataframe. From there, it should be straightforward to convert the data.frame to a data.table.